# Excel - Auto increment IP based on associated VLAN group

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I want to easily update a column with a new IP address based what VLAN it is currently assigned. The idea is to have the IP address self increment based on if the VLAN is part of the same subnet.

Lookup Table

```
D       E
VLANS   Subnet
VLAN10  10.0.26.
VLAN20  10.0.26.
VLAN30  10.0.26.
VLAN101 10.0.28.
VLAN102 10.0.28.
VLAN103 10.0.28.
```

Example Data of what I want

```
A       B
VLAN    New IP
VLAN10  10.0.26.1
VLAN10  10.0.26.2
VLAN10  10.0.26.3
VLAN101 10.0.28.1
VLAN101 10.0.28.2
VLAN101 10.0.28.3
VLAN30  10.0.26.4
VLAN20  10.0.26.5
VLAN20  10.0.26.6
VLAN103 10.0.28.4
VLAN101 10.0.28.5
```

I have this partially working with this formula on Column B

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$7,2,FALSE),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))
```

Results in this undesired output

```
VLAN    New IP
VLAN10  10.0.26.1
VLAN10  10.0.26.2
VLAN10  10.0.26.3
VLAN101 10.0.28.1
VLAN101 10.0.28.2
VLAN101 10.0.28.3
VLAN30  10.0.26.1
VLAN20  10.0.26.1
VLAN20  10.0.26.2
VLAN103 10.0.28.1
VLAN101 10.0.28.4
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to tell the formula to continue counting if the VLAN is part of the same subnet group. I know I need to group them together in an array maybe, but I'm kinda stuck as to how to do this.

Example Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJq2vZDcnbGMb3Hd3KOQpbCbeWA_8NGc2M8ni67P9NA/view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track, but lets use a wild card and count the subnets instead of the VLANS:

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$7,2,FALSE),COUNTIF($B$1:B1,VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$7,2,FALSE) & "*")+1)
```

[image]